# How to save multiple products details in one row in the database?(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to the laravel community but have to make a quick fix for my eCommerce website,
Currently, I have an OrderController that saves information to the database after Checking out,
The problem is, The Current Controller saves multiple products purchase at one time in multiple
new Order Columns in the Database I have been trying to fix on my own for a couple of days now without fully learning laravel as my website is live and I can't spend time learning Laravel.

This is The Code Block That fetches & saves Order details in the Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)   
{
    $carts = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();                                    

    if ($carts->isEmpty()) {
        flash(translate('Your cart is empty'))->warning();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    $shipping_info = Address::where('id', $carts[0]['address_id'])->first();                
    $shipping_info->name = Auth::user()->name;                                                 
    $shipping_info->email = Auth::user()->email;                                               
    if ($shipping_info->latitude || $shipping_info->longitude) {                              
        $shipping_info->lat_lang = $shipping_info->latitude . ',' . $shipping_info->longitude;
    }                                  
    $seller_products = array();              
    foreach ($carts as $cartItem){
        $product_ids = array();      
        $product = Product::find($cartItem['product_id']); 
        if(isset($seller_products[$product->user_id])){
            $product_ids = $seller_products[$product->user_id];
        }
        array_push($product_ids, $cartItem);
        $seller_products[$product->user_id] = $product_ids;
    }
        //Order Details Storing
        foreach ($seller_products as $cartItem) {
            $product = Product::find($cartItem['product_id']);

            $subtotal += $cartItem['price'] * $cartItem['quantity'];
            $tax += $cartItem['tax'] * $cartItem['quantity'];
            $coupon_discount += $cartItem['discount'];

            $product_variation = $cartItem['variation'];

            $product_stock = $product->stocks->where('variant', $product_variation)->first();
            if ($product->digital != 1 && $cartItem['quantity'] > $product_stock->qty) {
                flash(translate('The requested quantity is not available for ') . $product->getTranslation('name'))->warning();
                $order->delete();
                return redirect()->route('cart')->send();
            } elseif ($product->digital != 1) {
                $product_stock->qty -= $cartItem['quantity'];
                $product_stock->save();
            }
            
        }
            $order_detail = new OrderDetail;
            $order_detail->order_id = $order->id;
            $order_detail->seller_id = "$seller_products";
            $order_detail->product_id = $product->id;
            $order_detail->variation = $product_variation;
            $order_detail->price = $cartItem['price'] * $cartItem['quantity'];
            $order_detail->tax = $cartItem['tax'] * $cartItem['quantity'];
            $order_detail->shipping_type = $cartItem['shipping_type'];
            $order_detail->product_referral_code = $cartItem['product_referral_code'];
            $order_detail->shipping_cost = $cartItem['shipping_cost'];

            $shipping += $order_detail->shipping_cost;

            if ($cartItem['shipping_type'] == 'pickup_point') {
                $order_detail->pickup_point_id = $cartItem['pickup_point'];
            }
            //End of storing shipping cost

            $order_detail->quantity = $cartItem['quantity'];
            $order_detail->save();
```

Comment: Why not store json information in one column and the make a `json_decode()` to get the information in controller.

Comment: The thing is most of the information I am trying to store are integers, i tried that but when i json_decode them they're decoded as strings.